# Copy an image and save as new name in different folder

Tags: batch-file, copy, command, move, prompt

I have an image. Say its

`Cutedoggo.png` which is sitting on my desktop

I would like to copy it over, rename it , and save it to a new destination. Let's say I want to rename it to `Dog1.png` in the `c:/doggo` folder I've made

I tried in windows command prompt *(while inside the directory of original file)*

`copy CuteDoggo.png Dog1.png c:/doggo` but it didn't work. Error message

> error: the syntax of name is incorrect

how would I accomplish this using command prompt?

Comment: copy "CuteDoggo.png" "c:\doggo\Dog1.png"`

Comment: thanks stephan this works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

`copy "CuteDoggo.png" "c:\doggo\Dog1.png"`

also this works as well: (simplified)

`copy CuteDoggo.png c:\doggo\Dog1.png` **EDIT** this will not work if there's a space in folder.

courtesy of stephan

Comment: without the quotes, it will fail when there is a space in the file or folder name.

Comment: ah okay that makes sense I will use double quotes then and revise answer